How to access clipboard when undo doesn't work
In mathematica, undo is only available for once and not many times, then important information can be lost due to careless operations. How to get access to the clipboard to get previous contents saved in the clipboard by ctrl+c?

But I also wonder if there is anything like undo but which performs better than undo?
